# Mikros NullReferenceException

Tags: unity-game-engine, mikros-analytics, mikros-game-analytics

I followed the Mikros documentation to implement it into my Unity project (https://developer.tatumgames.com/documentation/getting-started).

- [Registered for mikros online and got a project approved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcFpu.png)
- [Imported the SDK and added my app keys into the mikros settings (no QA nor development keys)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EULCb.png)

Afterwards, my unity outputs [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJwpP.png) whenever I hit the play button in the editor (whenever I start the game and end it).

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
MikrosClient.UI.MikrosUiCanvas.OnEnable () (at <72d426ff4b8848e99e4576fb89764968>:0)
UnityEngine.Object:Instantiate(MikrosUiCanvas, Transform)
MikrosClient.UI.MikrosUiCanvas:CreateInstance()
```

While the error is a red error, the game is still fully functional. This error occurs without any additional code being added.

Note that I am using Unity version 2021.3.6f1 and Mikros 1.1.0

Comment: Seems like a bug within the MIKROS SDK. Did you speak to any of the developers in the MIKROS Slack community? To report the issue?

Comment: There is an update that should address your issue. Ref- https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/mikros-sdk-for-unity-211455?aid=1101lr4Lq